# LayerDrawable, strange behavior of setLayerInset

Tags: android, shapedrawable

I'm trying to create a Drawable for an ImageButton programmatically, using a LayerDrawable with 2 layers. Those layers are ShapeDrawables. One represents the button surface and its dimensions match the dimensions of the button. The second one is a sign on the button and it is smaller than the button. Think about a Stop button as an example.

I'm trying to use the combination of setIntrinsicWidth/setIntrinsicHeight and setLayerInset to place the sign into the button center but I get a strange result.

```
public Drawable createStopButtonDrawable(int width, int height) {
    //-- width = 60, height = 30
    ShapeDrawable button = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());      
    button.setIntrinsicHeight(height);
    button.setIntrinsicWidth(width);
    button.setShaderFactory(new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {         
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
            return new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, 
                    new int[]{0xCDCCCCCC, 0xCDFFFFFF, 0xCDCCCCCC}, 
                    new float[]{0, 0.3f, 1},
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        }
    });


    ShapeDrawable sign = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    int signSize = (int)(STOP_SIGN_SIZE_RATIO * (float)Math.min(width, height));
    //-- signSize = 12
    sign.setIntrinsicHeight(signSize);
    sign.setIntrinsicWidth(signSize);
    Paint psPaint = sign.getPaint();
    psPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    psPaint.setColor(PLAY_BUTTON_SIGN_COLOR);

    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[]{ button, sign };
    LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(layers);
    ld.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    ld.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    int sx = (int)( (width - signSize)/2.0f );
    //-- sx = 24
    int sy = (int)( (height - signSize)/2.0f );
    //-- sy = 9

    ld.setLayerInset(1, sx, sy, sx, sy);   //-- 1. Sign stretched
    //ld.setLayerInset(1, sx, 10, sx, 9);  //-- 2. Almost good
    return ld;
}
```

This produces the button with the sign stretched to match the button size.

[image: Sign stretched]

However, if I replace the line "1. Sign stretched" with "2. Almost good", I get almost the expected result.

[image: Sign is almost right]

What am I doing wrong?

I've noticed also that the displayed button surface has the size 59x29, not the expected 60x30.